Tyre in the rims won't stand upright? How to know if it is a rim or a tyre problem?
I have a bumpy ride at 90 to 110kph speed. When i try to remove the tyre from the car and let it stand upright it will fall down. Take note that this only happen on a single wheel (Tyre attach to a rim).
Is it a rim or tyre problem? Or not attach properly? How to check?
https://youtube.com/shorts/Wr3khQBNjP8?si=xRC13JaEITQ68wv1

That it tips over doesn't indicate a problem. If the rim is offset far enough, it will be a greater weight to one side, so would tip over. We don't know what your vehicle is or how your rims are setup.

Are your wheels/tires speed balanced? Wheel/tire assemblies are spun in a machine to determine imbalances and the computer points to position(s) for adding wheel weights to eliminate imbalance. The tire and rim must be in good condition, free of damage and roadworthy for high speed balancing.

Oh all the other tyres would stand right up. except just one tyre. My car is a Honda Stream 2009. (I had balanced it last year. So do you mean the tyre will stand up straight again if I balanced it in the shop? Thanks!

Are they all inflated to the correct pressure? If this one is over inflated, the tread will have a curvature which will make it less stable.

Yes, They are all inflated to the specified psi.  Went to the mechanic and let him check it. He just said its a tyre. Then he replaced the tyre and show me that it is standing up right now.
